# Sorting elements in an AngularFire array using a filter

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase, angular-filters

I use Angular with Firebase and now stuck with error when trying to make a factory to work with filter.

```
 app.factory('itemsFactory', ["$scope", '$rootScope', "$firebase", "simpleLogin", 
  function($scope, $rootScope, $firebase, simpleLogin) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://------.firebaseio.com/");
      var items = $scope.items
      $scope.items = [];
      var sync = $firebase(ref);
      $scope.items = sync.$asArray();
      $rootScope.auth = simpleLogin;

      return items;
   }]);

   app.filter('orderObjectBy',['itemsFactory', function (itemsFactory) {
     return function (items) {
       var filtered = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         var item = items[i];
         if (item.hot) {
           filtered.push(item);
         }
       };
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         var item = items[i];
         if (!item.hot) {
           filtered.push(item);
         }
       };
       return filtered;
     };
   }]);
```

This is the related HTML:

```
< tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy:'hot' track by $index">
```

Here's what i got in console:

> ngRepeat: item in items | orderObjectBy:"hot" track by $index
>   copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%itemsFactory%20%3C-%orderObjectByFilter at Error (native)

Seems I messed up with dependency injection. But what would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: If you're trying to only display hot items, why not either `item in items | filter:{hot:true}` or (even better) only retrieve the hot items from Firebase (e.g. by setting an item's hotness as its priority)?

Comment: The idea is to sort "hot" items first and all others later so your option will not work for me unfortunately.

Comment: So: `item in items | filter:{hot:true}` and then `item in items | filter:{hot:false}`. Or: set hotness as priority on the items and let Firebase return them in the order you want them in.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Your first option is to repeat my ng-repeat twice? That actually works and do gives me a proper result without a factory but not quite DRY. As for Firebase option — that is cool, didn't even knew about it, but i'd really love to solve this task Angule Way.

Comment: It looks like your syntax is a little off. I think it should read: `ng-repeat="item in items track by $id | orderObjectBy:'hot'"`. Note that track by is before the filter and additionally, we track by $id (unique) not $index (fluid)

Comment: The fact that you're writing code to **order** an array in a method called `filter` should be a dead give-away that the mapping is wrong. It **can** probably be made to work, but why would you not use Firebase's ordering mechanism?

Comment: @Kato: your comment might be better as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, was working on that. Unfortunately, I can't seem to answer with anything shorter than a chapter. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of AngularFire's extensibility to order the list without the need for a directive:

```
app.factory('HotList', function($firebase) {   
  function hotComparator(a,b) {
    if( a.hot === b.hot ) {
      // if both are hot or not, then sort by $id
      return strcmp(a.$id, b.$id);
    }
    else {
      // place hot items at the top
      return a.hot? -1 : 1;
    }
  }

  function strcmp(str1, str2) {
    //  http://phpjs.org/functions/strcmp/
    return ((str1 == str2) ? 0 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : -1));
  }

  return function(ref) {
    var list = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
    function resort() {
      list.sort(hotComparator);
    }
    list.$watch(resort);
    resort();
    return list;
  };
});

app.controller('ctrl', function(HotList) {
   // automagically sorted by hot/not and $id
   $scope.list = HotList(new Firebase(URL));
});
```

To make your directive work in place, you will want to copy the array and call sort on the copy which will be a great deal simpler.

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function($firebase) {   
  function hotComparator(a,b) {
    if( a.hot === b.hot ) {
      // if both are hot or not, then sort by $id
      return strcmp(a.$id, b.$id);
    }
    else {
      // place hot items at the top
      return a.hot? -1 : 1;
    }
  }

  function strcmp(str1, str2) {
    //  http://phpjs.org/functions/strcmp/
    return ((str1 == str2) ? 0 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : -1));
  }

  return function(items) {
    var list = items.slice();
    list.sort(hotComparator);
    return list;
  };
});
```

And your usage in the view is not quite right, so try it this way:

```
ng-repeat="item in items track by $id | orderObjectBy:'hot'"
```

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Really elegant solution. But i got undefined on $scope.list — must be some silly error that i can't track.